# how to get the right position when used rotateOnAxis

Tags: position

cube_group.children[i].rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), 180 * ( Math.PI/180 ));

I use rotateOnAxis to rotate a object, for example,rotate a object on (10,10,10) around x_axis 180 degrees, and then ,the object's position should be (10,-10,-10),but when I use object.position to get the object's position,it is (10,10,10),so how can I get the right position when I used rotateOnAxis to rotate a object?